# asp.net how to use multi form in masterpage?

Tags: asp.net, forms, post

[image]

I have 5 tabs in my content page and when i click save,asp page post all data.All data means,post all object value to server in each tabs.

I want to post only "Header Info" 's objects.So i try to set 5 different  tag but it doesnt work.

How can seperate tabs operations ?

Masterpage:

```
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager AsyncPostBackTimeOut="36000" runat="server" />

        <div class="main" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

MainContent:

```
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
        <li class="tabs-baslik"><a href="#tabs-1">
            <%= GetTranslate("Admin_HeaderInfo") %></a></li>
        <li class="tabs-kolonlar"><a href="#tabs-2">
            <%= GetTranslate("Admin_Columns") %></a></li>
        <li class="tabs-aksiyon"><a href="#tabs-3">
            <%= GetTranslate("Admin_Actions") %></a></li>
        <li class="tabs-kutuphane"><a href="#tabs-4">
            <%= GetTranslate("Admin_Dictionary") %></a></li>
        <li class="tabs-cizelge"><a href="#tabs-5">
            <%= GetTranslate("Admin_Schedule") %></a></li>
        <li class="tabs-yetki"><a href="#tabs-6">
            <%= GetTranslate("Admin_AuthorizationShortName") %></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
         ..
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
         ..
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
         ..
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-4">
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
         ..
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-5">
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server">
         ..
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

    </ul>

  </div>
```

Comment: it's javascript tab right?

Comment: can you check which tab is selected through code?

Comment: i have one form so when i click a submit button my post value sends all data,i can trace posted value on chrome developer tools.

Comment: i was thinking about checking which tab was selected and then save the data of this tab only but it seems that this will not be able to work or achieve it